# jpa query with two parameters

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two parameters say name and description of state entity.

1. If the name and desc are not mentioned, then the query should return all the states.
2. If the only name is mentioned the filtered list of states which matched the passed name should be returned
3. If the only desc is passed, the list of states matching the description should be returned.
4. Only if both name and description are passed, then the result should contain all the states which either match the name or description should be returned.

I have written the JPA query like below:

```
@Query("select s from State s where (:name is null or s.name = :name) or (:desc is null or s.desc=:desc)")
List<State> fetchStates(@Param("name") String name,  @Param("desc") String description, Pageable pageable);
```

SQL query generated:

```
select state0_.state_id as state1_24_, state0_.created_date as creation2_24_, state0_.desc as descript3_24_, state0_.name as name4_24_ from state state0_ where ? is null or state0_.name=? or ? is null or state0_.desc=? order by state0_.name desc limit ?
```

I guess, if we have more than one parameter, we cannot write the dynamic query to get the desired result. Please let me know if my assumption is right else where I am missing. I am new to JPA.

Comment: JPQL allows you to write a query with as many parameters as you want. This is not JPA however, it is "Spring Data JPA"

Comment: This is just a JPQL query... However for dynamic queries you are better of writing a `Specification` instead of these kind of queries.

Comment: @Deinum can you please point me to the link which you are referring to

Comment: @NeilStockton can you please throw some more light on what is the approach.

Comment: No, since I use JPA API, not Spring Data JPA. Wrap your code in these layers and you have to dig through their docs

Comment: An easy way to frame a JPA query for this scenario would be `SELECT s FROM state s WHERE s.name = COALESCE(:name, s.name) OR s.description = COALESCE(:description, s.description)`. However, this query may perform poorly at runtime when `:name` and/or `:description` have not been specified as the `WHERE` clauses could still be part of the  query execution plan. If performance is a worry, the query must be generated dynamically using Spring Data `Specification`s, JPA `Criteria` or QueryDSL.